# Android Java - Issue whith setVisibility for Button

Tags: java, android

I'm dealing with this issue for quite a while, I'm trying to show two buttons on an event condition, specifically this one.

```
            player.on(PlayerEvent.TimeChanged.class,
                (event) -> {
                    context.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit("timeChanged", event.getTime()); 
                    if (Math.floor(event.getTime()) > nextContentStart) {
                        Log.e("ReactNative",""+Math.round(event.getTime()));
                        Log.e("ReactNative",""+nextContentStart);
                        Log.d("ReactNative", "here IF"); //gets here no problem
                        nextBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //crashes here
                        creditsBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                }
        );
```

It crashes on the part that is commented (nextBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)).

I guess it's got to be related to the IF clause being looped inside an event emmiter?

Here's the rest of the code:

PlayerActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.bitmovin.player.PlayerView;
import com.bitmovin.player.api.Player;
import com.bitmovin.player.api.drm.DrmConfig;
import com.bitmovin.player.api.drm.WidevineConfig;
import com.bitmovin.player.api.event.Event;
import com.bitmovin.player.api.event.PlayerEvent;
import com.bitmovin.player.api.source.Source;
import com.bitmovin.player.api.source.SourceConfig;
import com.bitmovin.player.api.source.SourceOptions;
import com.bitmovin.player.api.source.SourceType;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.app.Activity;

public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PlayerView playerView;
    private Player player;
    private String dashUrl;
    private String hlsUrl;
    private String posterUrl;
    private String drmToken;
    private double watchedSeconds;
    private double durationSeconds;
    private double nextContentStart;

    public static final String CONTENT_ID = "SOURCE_CONTENT_ID";
    public static final String DASH_URL = "SOURCE_DASH_URL";
    public static final String HLS_URL = "SOURCE_HLS_URL";
    public static final String TITLE = "SOURCE_TITLE";
    public static final String DESCRIPTION = "SOURCE_DESCRIPTION";
    public static final String POSTER = "SOURCE_POSTER";
    public static final String DRM_TOKEN = "SOURCE_DRM_TOKEN";
    public static final String WATCHED_SECONDS = "WATCHED_SECONDS";
    public static final String DURATION_SECONDS = "DURATION_SECONDS";
    public static final String NEXT_CONTENT_START = "NEXT_CONTENT_START";

    public static final String WIDEVINE_LICENSE_URL = "https://widevine-license.vudrm.tech/proxy";

    public static Activity activity = null;

    Button nextBtn;
    Button creditsBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activity = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bitmovin_player);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        init(getIntent());
        loadSource();
    }

    private void loadSource() {
        SourceConfig sourceConfig = null;
        if (dashUrl != null && !dashUrl.isEmpty()) {
            sourceConfig = new SourceConfig(dashUrl, SourceType.Dash);
        } else if (hlsUrl != null && !hlsUrl.isEmpty()) {
            sourceConfig = new SourceConfig(hlsUrl, SourceType.Hls);
        }

        if (sourceConfig != null) {
            if (posterUrl != null) {
                sourceConfig.setPosterImage(posterUrl, false);
            }
            if (drmToken != null) {
                WidevineConfig drmConfig = new WidevineConfig(WIDEVINE_LICENSE_URL);
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("x-vudrm-token", drmToken);
                drmConfig.setHttpHeaders(headers);
                sourceConfig.setDrmConfig(drmConfig);
            }
            if ( watchedSeconds > 0 ) {
                SourceOptions options = new SourceOptions();
                options.setStartOffset(watchedSeconds);
                sourceConfig.setOptions(options);
            }
            Source source = Source.create(sourceConfig);
            playerView = this.findViewById(R.id.playerView);
            player = playerView.getPlayer();
            addTrackListener();

            player.on(PlayerEvent.Ready.class, (event) -> player.play());
            player.load(source);
            player.on(PlayerEvent.PlaybackFinished.class, (event) -> player.unload());

            nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
            creditsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.creditsButton);
            nextBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            creditsBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ReactContext context = ((MainApplication) getApplication()).getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext();
            nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    context.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit("nextBtn", player.getCurrentTime());
                }
            });
            creditsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    context.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit("creditsBtn", player.getCurrentTime());
                    creditsBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    nextBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private void setDimensions(View view, int width, int height){
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        params.height = height;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        Log.e("ReactNative",""+playerView.getWidth());
        Log.e("ReactNative",""+playerView.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("ReactNative", "onNewINtent");
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        init(intent);
        loadSource();
    }
        
    private void init(Intent intent) {
        dashUrl = intent.getStringExtra(DASH_URL);
        hlsUrl = intent.getStringExtra(HLS_URL);
        posterUrl = intent.getStringExtra(POSTER);
        drmToken = intent.getStringExtra(DRM_TOKEN);
        watchedSeconds = intent.getDoubleExtra(WATCHED_SECONDS, 0);
        durationSeconds = intent.getDoubleExtra(DURATION_SECONDS, 0);
        nextContentStart = intent.getDoubleExtra(NEXT_CONTENT_START, 0);
    }

    private void addTrackListener() {
        ReactContext context = ((MainApplication) getApplication()).getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext();
        if (context != null) {
            player.on(PlayerEvent.TimeChanged.class,
                    (event) -> {
                        context.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit("timeChanged", event.getTime());
                       
                        if (Math.floor(event.getTime()) > nextContentStart) {
                            Log.e("ReactNative",""+Math.round(event.getTime()));
                            Log.e("ReactNative",""+nextContentStart);
                            Log.d("ReactNative", "here IF"); //gets here no problem
                            nextBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //crashes here
                            creditsBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                       
                    }
            );
            player.on(PlayerEvent.Seeked.class,
                    (event) -> context.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit("timeSeeked", player.getCurrentTime()));
            player.on(PlayerEvent.PlaybackFinished.class,
                    (event) -> context.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit("timeFinished", player.getCurrentTime()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        playerView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        playerView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        playerView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        playerView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        ReactContext context = ((MainApplication) getApplication()).getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext();
        if (context != null) {
            context.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit("timeExited", player.getCurrentTime());
        }
        playerView.onDestroy();
    }

    public static void close() {
        PlayerActivity.activity.finish();
    }

}
```

activity_bitmovin_player.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.bitmovin.player.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/nextButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="34dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="54dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/creditsButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="167dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
                android:text="Watch credits" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.bitmovin.player.PlayerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance,

EDIT:
Adding stack trace:

```
05-01 15:49:31.352  6870  7040 E ReactNative: 86
05-01 15:49:31.352  6870  7040 E ReactNative: 85.0
05-01 15:49:31.587  6870  7040 E ReactNative: 86
05-01 15:49:31.587  6870  7040 E ReactNative: 85.0
05-01 15:49:31.587  6870  7040 D ReactNative: here if // this seems to be where the code crashes
05-01 15:49:31.593  6870  6870 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myappapp, PID: 6870
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:9316)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1772)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25697)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25697)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25697)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25697)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25697)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25697)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:380)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25697)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25697)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:380)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:25697)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:16377)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:11896)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.myappapp.PlayerActivity.lambda$addTrackListener$2$PlayerActivity(PlayerActivity.java:181)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.myappapp.-$$Lambda$PlayerActivity$4drhB4sZ6Yh1cjccm1TfDL1Tp1Y.onEvent(Unknown Source:6)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.bitmovin.player.api.event.EventEmitter$DefaultImpls$d.a(SourceFile:1)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.bitmovin.player.api.event.EventEmitter$DefaultImpls$d.invoke(SourceFile:1)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.bitmovin.player.event.b.b(SourceFile:206)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.bitmovin.player.event.d.a(SourceFile:1)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.bitmovin.player.n.s0.d$a.run(SourceFile:8)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:562)
05-01 15:49:31.603  6870  6870 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:512)
05-01 15:49:31.624   569  7154 I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=data_app_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
05-01 15:49:31.627   569  2465 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.myappapp/.PlayerActivity
05-01 15:49:31.636   339   375 D goldfish-address-space: claimShared: Ask to claim region [0x1fb110000 0x1fb73c000]
05-01 15:49:31.650   322  7155 D resolv  : GetAddrInfoHandler::run: {100 100 100 983140 10146 0}
05-01 15:49:31.650   322  7155 D resolv  : resolv_getaddrinfo: explore_fqdn(): ai_family=0 ai_socktype=1 ai_protocol=6
05-01 15:49:31.650   322  7155 D resolv  : android_getaddrinfofornetcontext: explore_numeric: ai_family=10 ai_socktype=1 ai_protocol=6
05-01 15:49:31.650   322  7155 D resolv  : explore_numeric_scope
05-01 15:49:31.650   322  7155 D resolv  : android_getaddrinfofornetcontext: explore_numeric: ai_family=2 ai_socktype=1 ai_protocol=6
05-01 15:49:31.650   322  7155 D resolv  : explore_numeric_scope
05-01 15:49:31.650   322  7155 I ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
05-01 15:49:31.743   569   618 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
05-01 15:49:31.744   569   618 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
05-01 15:49:31.775  6870  7121 D CCodecBuffers: [c2.goldfish.h264.decoder#432:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 0)
05-01 15:49:31.780  6870  7121 D CCodecBuffers: [c2.goldfish.h264.decoder#432:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 1)
05-01 15:49:31.807   569   608 D CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 171228096; UID 1000; state: ENABLED
05-01 15:49:31.822   569   608 D CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 168419799; UID 1000; state: DISABLED
05-01 15:49:31.843   569   611 D CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 158002302; UID 1000; state: ENABLED
05-01 15:49:31.843   339   375 D goldfish-address-space: claimShared: Ask to claim region [0x1f8000000 0x1f8634000]
05-01 15:49:31.844   339   375 D goldfish-address-space: claimShared: Ask to claim region [0x1f8634000 0x1f8c68000]
05-01 15:49:31.845   339   375 D goldfish-address-space: claimShared: Ask to claim region [0x1f8c68000 0x1f929c000]
05-01 15:49:32.169   569   610 W ActivityTaskManager: Activity top resumed state loss timeout for ActivityRecord{bb0b6da u0 com.myappapp/.PlayerActivity t14 f}}
05-01 15:49:32.172   569   610 W ActivityTaskManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{bb0b6da u0 com.myappapp/.PlayerActivity t14 f}}
05-01 15:49:32.956  6870  7117 D BufferPoolAccessor2.0: bufferpool2 0xb400007927a9b758 : 4(32768 size) total buffers - 4(32768 size) used buffers - 1/6 (recycle/alloc) - 5/885 (fetch/transfer)
05-01 15:49:32.958  6870  7121 D CCodecBuffers: [c2.android.aac.decoder#316:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 0)
05-01 15:49:33.287  6870  7121 D CCodecBuffers: [c2.android.aac.decoder#316:1D-Input.Impl[N]] codec released a buffer owned by client (index 0)
05-01 15:49:33.545   428  7122 D BufferPoolAccessor2.0: bufferpool2 0xb400007421629e18 : 5(20480 size) total buffers - 1(4096 size) used buffers - 898/903 (recycle/alloc) - 9/902 (fetch/transfer)
05-01 15:49:33.655   322  7163 D resolv  : GetAddrInfoHandler::run: {100 100 100 983140 10146 0}
05-01 15:49:33.656   322  7163 D resolv  : resolv_getaddrinfo: explore_fqdn(): ai_family=0 ai_socktype=1 ai_protocol=6
05-01 15:49:33.656   322  7163 D resolv  : android_getaddrinfofornetcontext: explore_numeric: ai_family=10 ai_socktype=1 ai_protocol=6
05-01 15:49:33.656   322  7163 D resolv  : explore_numeric_scope
05-01 15:49:33.656   322  7163 D resolv  : android_getaddrinfofornetcontext: explore_numeric: ai_family=2 ai_socktype=1 ai_protocol=6
05-01 15:49:33.656   322  7163 D resolv  : explore_numeric_scope
05-01 15:49:33.656   322  7163 I ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
05-01 15:49:33.774  6870  7123 D BufferPoolAccessor2.0: bufferpool2 0xb400007927a7b5f8 : 4(8388608 size) total buffers - 4(8388608 size) used buffers - 0/4 (recycle/alloc) - 4/537 (fetch/transfer)
05-01 15:49:35.662   322  7164 D resolv  : GetAddrInfoHandler::run: {100 100 100 983140 10146 0}
05-01 15:49:35.662   322  7164 D resolv  : resolv_getaddrinfo: explore_fqdn(): ai_family=0 ai_socktype=1 ai_protocol=6
05-01 15:49:35.663   322  7164 D resolv  : android_getaddrinfofornetcontext: explore_numeric: ai_family=10 ai_socktype=1 ai_protocol=6
05-01 15:49:35.663   322  7164 D resolv  : explore_numeric_scope
05-01 15:49:35.663   322  7164 D resolv  : android_getaddrinfofornetcontext: explore_numeric: ai_family=2 ai_socktype=1 ai_protocol=6
05-01 15:49:35.663   322  7164 D resolv  : explore_numeric_scope
05-01 15:49:35.663   322  7164 I ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (100, <unspecified>/0)
05-01 15:49:36.717   569   682 W InputDispatcher: Window d44ceaf com.myappapp/com.myappapp.PlayerActivity (server) is unresponsive: d44ceaf com.myappapp/com.myappapp.PlayerActivity (server) is not responding. Waited 5004ms for FocusEvent(hasFocus=false)
05-01 15:49:36.717   569   682 W InputDispatcher: Canceling events for d44ceaf com.myappapp/com.myappapp.PlayerActivity (server) because it is unresponsive
05-01 15:49:36.723   569   682 I WindowManager: ANR in com.myappapp/com.myappapp.PlayerActivity. Reason:d44ceaf com.myappapp/com.myappapp.PlayerActivity (server) is not responding. Waited 5004ms for FocusEvent(hasFocus=false)
05-01 15:49:36.820   569  7167 I ActivityManager: Crashing app skipping ANR: com.android.server.am.ProcessErrorStateRecord@95dcf9b Input dispatching timed out (d44ceaf com.myappapp/com.myappapp.PlayerActivity (server) is not responding. Waited 5004ms for FocusEvent(hasFocus=false))
05-01 15:49:36.820   569  7167 D ActivityManager: Completed ANR of com.myappapp in 22ms, latency 0ms
05-01 15:49:37.189   569   610 I ActivityTaskManager: Config changes=20000480 {1.0 310mcc260mnc [en_US] ldltr sw392dp w392dp h778dp 440dpi nrml long port finger qwerty/v/v dpad/v winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2208) mMaxBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mDisplayWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined mAlwaysOnTop=undefined mRotation=ROTATION_0} s.68 fontWeightAdjustment=0}
05-01 15:49:37.217   569   610 W ActivityTaskManager: Current config: {1.0 310mcc260mnc [en_US] ldltr sw392dp w802dp h368dp 440dpi nrml long land finger qwerty/v/v dpad/v winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 2340, 1080) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 2208, 1080) mMaxBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 2340, 1080) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mDisplayWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined mAlwaysOnTop=undefined mRotation=ROTATION_90} s.68 fontWeightAdjustment=0} unchanged for IME proc com.google.android.inputmethod.latin
05-01 15:49:37.221   569   610 I WindowManager: Override config changes=20000480 {1.0 310mcc260mnc [en_US] ldltr sw392dp w392dp h778dp 440dpi nrml long port finger qwerty/v/v dpad/v winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2208) mMaxBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mDisplayWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined mAlwaysOnTop=undefined mRotation=ROTATION_0} s.68 fontWeightAdjustment=0} for displayId=0
05-01 15:49:37.231   569   610 V ActivityTaskManager: Sending to IME proc com.google.android.inputmethod.latin new config {1.0 310mcc260mnc [en_US] ldltr sw392dp w392dp h778dp 440dpi nrml long port finger qwerty/v/v dpad/v winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2208) mMaxBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mDisplayWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined mAlwaysOnTop=undefined mRotation=ROTATION_0} s.68 fontWeightAdjustment=0}
05-01 15:49:37.270   569   610 I InputManager-JNI: Viewport [0] to add: local:4619827259835644672, isActive: true
05-01 15:49:37.274   569   683 I InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices, changes=DISPLAY_INFO | 
05-01 15:49:37.274   569   683 I InputReader: Touch device 'virtio_input_multi_touch_10' could not query the properties of its associated display.  The device will be inoperable until the display size becomes available.
05-01 15:49:37.274   569   683 I InputReader: Touch device 'virtio_input_multi_touch_6' could not query the properties of its associated display.  The device will be inoperable until the display size becomes available.
05-01 15:49:37.274   569   683 I InputReader: Touch device 'virtio_input_multi_touch_11' could not query the properties of its associated display.  The device will be inoperable until the display size becomes available.
05-01 15:49:37.274   569   683 I InputReader: Touch device 'virtio_input_multi_touch_4' could not query the properties of its associated display.  The device will be inoperable until the display size becomes available.
05-01 15:49:37.274   569   683 I InputReader: Device reconfigured: id=8, name='virtio_input_multi_touch_1', size 1080x2340, orientation 0, mode 1, display id 0
05-01 15:49:37.274   569   683 I InputReader: Touch device 'virtio_input_multi_touch_7' could not query the properties of its associated display.  The device will be inoperable until the display size becomes available.
05-01 15:49:37.274   569   683 I InputReader: Touch device 'virtio_input_multi_touch_2' could not query the properties of its associated display.  The device will be inoperable until the display size becomes available.
05-01 15:49:37.274   569   683 I InputReader: Touch device 'virtio_input_multi_touch_9' could not query the properties of its associated display.  The device will be inoperable until the display size becomes available.
05-01 15:49:37.274   569   683 I InputReader: Touch device 'virtio_input_multi_touch_5' could not query the properties of its associated display.  The device will be inoperable until the display size becomes available.
05-01 15:49:37.274   569   683 I InputReader: Touch device 'virtio_input_multi_touch_3' could not query the properties of its associated display.  The device will be inoperable until the display size becomes available.
05-01 15:49:37.274   569   683 I InputReader: Touch device 'virtio_input_multi_touch_8' could not query the properties of its associated display.  The device will be inoperable until the display size becomes available.
05-01 15:49:37.279   825   825 D StatusBar: disable<e i a s b h r c s > disable2<q i n >
05-01 15:49:37.290  1440  1440 W GoogleInputMethodService: GoogleInputMethodService.onConfigurationChanged():1661 onConfigurationChanged() : NewConfig = {1.0 310mcc260mnc [en_US] ldltr sw392dp w392dp h778dp 440dpi nrml long port finger qwerty/v/v dpad/v winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2208) mMaxBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mDisplayWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined mAlwaysOnTop=undefined mRotation=ROTATION_0} s.104 fontWeightAdjustment=0}
05-01 15:49:37.303  1440  1440 I NormalModeController: NormalModeController.getKeyboardBodyViewHolderPaddingBottom():109 currentPrimeKeyboardType:SOFT systemPaddingBottom:-1
05-01 15:49:37.307   339   375 D goldfish-address-space: claimShared: Ask to claim region [0x1f7664000 0x1f79ac000]
05-01 15:49:37.307  1440  1440 I AbstractOpenableExtension: AbstractOpenableExtension.maybeDestroyExistingKeyboardGroupManager():514 Destroy existing keyboard group manager in fau
05-01 15:49:37.308  1440  1440 I AbstractOpenableExtension: AbstractOpenableExtension.createKeyboardGroupManagerListenableFuture():123 Create keyboard group manager listenable future in fau
05-01 15:49:37.312  1107  1379 D TelephonyProvider: subIdString = 1 subId = 1
05-01 15:49:37.313  1107  1379 D TelephonyProvider: subIdString = 1 subId = 1
05-01 15:49:37.314  1440  1440 I AbstractOpenableExtension: AbstractOpenableExtension.maybeDestroyExistingKeyboardGroupManager():514 Destroy existing keyboard group manager in eyj
05-01 15:49:37.314  1440  1440 I AbstractOpenableExtension: AbstractOpenableExtension.createKeyboardGroupManagerListenableFuture():123 Create keyboard group manager listenable future in eyj
05-01 15:49:37.314  1440  1440 I AbstractOpenableExtension: AbstractOpenableExtension.maybeDestroyExistingKeyboardGroupManager():514 Destroy existing keyboard group manager in fci
05-01 15:49:37.314  1440  1440 I AbstractOpenableExtension: AbstractOpenableExtension.createKeyboardGroupManagerListenableFuture():123 Create keyboard group manager listenable future in fci
05-01 15:49:37.318  1440  7133 I KeyboardGroupDefParser: KeyboardGroupDefParser.parseKeyboardGroupDef():89 parseKeyboardGroupDef() 2132148494 -> 0_resource_name_obfuscated : WaitTime = 0 ms : RunTime = 3 ms
05-01 15:49:37.319  1440  7135 I KeyboardGroupDefParser: KeyboardGroupDefParser.parseKeyboardGroupDef():89 parseKeyboardGroupDef() 2132148499 -> 0_resource_name_obfuscated : WaitTime = 1 ms : RunTime = 3 ms
05-01 15:49:37.322  1440  7169 I KeyboardGroupDefParser: KeyboardGroupDefParser.parseKeyboardGroupDef():89 parseKeyboardGroupDef() 2132148495 -> 0_resource_name_obfuscated : WaitTime = 6 ms : RunTime = 3 ms
05-01 15:49:37.322  1440  1440 I NormalModeController: NormalModeController.getKeyboardBodyViewHolderPaddingBottom():109 currentPrimeKeyboardType:SOFT systemPaddingBottom:-1
05-01 15:49:37.336  1440  1440 I GoogleInputMethodService: GoogleInputMethodService.initializeKeyboardTheme():1399 Apply keyboard theme: theme_border_bottom4dp_keyboard4dp_stylesheet_googleblue_materiallight_builtin_google_blue_light.binarypb_port
05-01 15:49:37.338   339   375 D goldfish-address-space: claimShared: Ask to claim region [0x1f6694000 0x1f69dc000]
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting? "_it crashes_" is not useful.

Comment: ... is `nextBtn` null?

Comment: It's very difficult to debug a crash without a stack trace. See [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](/q/23353173) for Android-specific advice, and [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](/q/3988788) for advice on what to do once you have the stack trace.  If you still need help, edit your question to include the **complete stack trace**, as well as **which line of your code** the stack trace points to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a race in your code of whether a `PlayerEvent.TimeChanged` event will fire before you initialize your buttons.

Move the below lines to somewhere above the call to `addTrackListener()` in `loadSource()` to guarantee they are already initialized by the time you register the listener.

```
creditsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.creditsButton);
nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
```

The additional error in the question update also pointed to view updates being posted from a background thread. To run these on the main thread, use a `Handler`:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(
  () -> {
    nextBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    creditsBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it didn't solve the issue

Comment: With your update, you need to wrap your updates to views to run on the main thread. `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper).post()` will do that for you.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked

                            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    nextBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    creditsBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                            });